# AndroidX RecyclerView row height won't wrap

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

I've been using the new Androidx libraries and have run into an issue I cannot fix. I am using `RecyclerView` and just cannot get the row to wrap. It is supposed to do it, and everything I read seems to be that it just works if I cannot get it right. I have used this previously and did not have this issue. I've tried adjusting every setting in both my main layout and the item layout, but nothing seems to affect it. Any help would be appreciated.

**main_activity.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cardRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:spanCount="4"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_card_preview"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorSecondary" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>
            <variable
                name="card"
                type="com.jibmobile.clashroyaltoolkit.vo.CardPreview"/>


        </data>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            image="@{card.name}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@{card.displayName}"
            tools:src="@drawable/archers" />
```

Answer (score 0):

OK in my case , in item.xml, the height was given "match_parent". After I converted it into "wrap_content", the recycle view height was expanded according to the number of items. Note that I am using the androidx library as well.

The item.xml code was like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/small_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tickred"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_between_text"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/serviceTv"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="top"
        app:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_smallx"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I changed the container height to wrap_content and the recycleview takes its height accordingly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/small_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tickred"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_between_text"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/serviceTv"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="top"
        app:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_text_smallx"/>

</LinearLayout>
```